# Server Sent Events: EventSource throws MIME error

Tags: php, server-sent-events

I am trying to use server sent events for the first time. I am creating a very simple test:

```php
// sse-test.php
<?php
header("Content-type: text/event-stream");
header("Cache-Control: no-store");

$time = date('r');
echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

```js
// inside index.html
...
const source = new EventSource("sse_test.php");

// check headers  
fetch('/sse-test.php')
.then(res => {
  for (let value of res.headers.values()) {
    console.log(value)
  }
})
```

The EventSource constructor throws a `EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection` error.
I am logging the response headers and they seem to be correct, they include a `text/event-stream;` header.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could it be not using the leading forward-slash on your `EventSource()` call? Which OS/browser is it? Take a look at the developer tools - that is a simpler way to troubleshoot if the correct headings are being sent than using `fetch()`.

Comment: I added the slash to the `EventSource()` call but the same thing happens. The fetch test was unecessary indeed, I see from the developer tools that I am getting the `text/html` content type. I am using Windows 10 with the https://github.com/cretueusebiu/valet-windows environment. This is using the nginx server, and maybe this needs some configuration for SSE to run properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not send an AJAX request to the Event Source server - you connect as you do above using `new EventSource` but then bind event handlers to the returned `event-stream`

A fully working basic example might help.

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_GET['sse'], $_GET['evt'] ) && $_GET['sse']=='go' ){
        # this script will run infinitely whilst client is connected so no timeout
        set_time_limit( 0 );
        
        # ensure no stray characters in event stream other than those created in the sse function below
        ob_end_clean();

        # repeat the infinite loop after a delay
        $sleep=1;
        
        # the name of the event.. this is sent in the connection url
        $evt=$_GET['evt'];
        
        #utility to send a correctly formatted message
        function sse( $evtname='sse', $data=null, $retry=1000 ){
            if( !is_null( $data ) ){
                echo "event:".$evtname."\r\n";
                echo "retry:".$retry."\r\n";
                echo "data:" . json_encode( $data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS );
                echo "\r\n\r\n";
            }
        }   
        
        # ensure that this header is set before starting the infinite loop.
        header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
        while( true ){
            /*
                Do whatever needs to be done - query db,
                query remote api, perform calculations etc
                
                prepare payload to send
            */
            $payload=array(
                'data'      =>  rand( 0, 100 ),
                'date'      =>  date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' )
            );
            
            #send the packet
            sse( $evt, $payload );
            
            # flush buffers
            if( @ob_get_level() > 0 ) for( $i=0; $i < @ob_get_level(); $i++ ) @ob_flush();
            @flush();
            
            # take it easy for a while before doing it all again.
            sleep( $sleep );
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Welcome!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div id="result"></div>
        
        <script>
        
            const evt='SOME_EVENT_NAME';
        
            // single page - connect with querystring parameters
            let sse = new EventSource( '?sse=go&evt='+evt );
            
            // bind the event listener and process response from server.
            sse.addEventListener(evt,e=>{
                console.log(e.data);
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=e.data;
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think he was just using `fetch()` to troubleshoot, i.e. to confirm that the correct headers were being sent? BTW, interesting example to combine HTML and the SSE PHP in one file; I'd never tried that.

Comment: One can inspect the text-stream using the console as one would for AJAX requests - no need for the separate ajax request. The only thing I notice about the @OPs code is the disparity between the url used for the EventSource and the Fetch request. I guess it is possible that one of these is not found, thus the non `text/event-stream` headers

Comment: I was using fetch to troubleshoot as @DarrenCook said, which was unnecessary after all.

Comment: Have you now resolved the issue?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius No, the headers from the php file are not sent.

Comment: Sorry, I just tried your example and it works. The SSE needs to be inside of a loop? I was hoping to be able to send a single event, just to inform the front-end of an action that happens in the back-end.

Comment: @AlexP I don't think it would be the loop - you can e.g. sleep 30 seconds then send one event and exit. Try removing the loop, then other bits of the working code until you break it.

Comment: With the loop it prevents the client from reconnecting every so often which it will do with a single message from the server. But there is no specific need for the infinite loop - as @DarrenCook says, remove that portion of the sse script but then, clientside, you'll probably want to ensure it does not reconnect

Comment: Also look at formatting the message more completely, perhaps just nick the `sse($evt,$data)` function and try with that